# PHP associate arrays, multidimension. How do I access them?

Tags: php, xml

I'm having hard time wrapping my head around this. I have an array called $a and here's what print_r shows:

```
Array
(
    [Rows] => Array
        (
            [Row] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ContactId] => 26525fea-20c5-43e5-afd2-0001
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ContactId] => 73b402e6-f7b9-45da-89f4-0002
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [ContactId] => e6a1f356-7838-494b-8e1e-000
                        )
```

How do I do an echo of just the data in number 2? I just want to output "e6a1f356-7838-494b-8e1e-000". Thanks.

edit: Thanks for the excellent replies. Also, I cant figure out how to do a sizeof of this array? Will I need to write a for loop to go through each until its empty or does sizeof somehow work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any array variable name can have `['key']` or `[N]` after it to access a value in the array.  If that value is also an array, you can put another set of `[]` to access values in that array, which is the next level:

```
echo $a['Rows']['Row'][2]['ContactId'];
```

Comment: Note the OP said the array was `$a`. Also it's good practice to single quote keys, albeit a micro optimization.

Comment: Thanks. As for the `"`, I do know that, but I'm in Java mode right now, so it was force of habit.

Comment: No worries. You've added some good additional info in your edit too.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I kept appending the [2] on the end, thinking that the number goes on the end. Your example works great. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, any idea on how to do a sizeof of this array in regards to the items in contactid? Or will I need to write a loop that can run through all these until fail and report back the number?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it'd be:

```
echo $a['Rows']['Row'][2]['ContactId'];
```

Comment: Fixed, too used to accessing my own, it seems :P

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse/access an array by its keys as shown by the `print_r()` output.

For example:

```
echo $a['Rows']['Row'][2]['ConactId'];
```