# How to parse JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I need help with something..

How can I parse data in this format: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

I tried set up a code in php

```
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
print_r($json);
```

This will list all the values like this..

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => bitcoin [name] => Bitcoin [symbol] =>
>   BTC [rank] => 1 [price_usd] => 2448.04 [price_btc] => 1.0
>   [24h_volume_usd] => 1935820000.0 [market_cap_usd] => 40128026876.0
>   [available_supply] => 16391900.0 [total_supply] => 16391900.0
>   [percent_change_1h] => 3.47 [percent_change_24h] => -11.1
>   [percent_change_7d] => -12.29 [last_updated] => 1497512954 ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [id] => ...

How can I access certain values. For example if I want to display "name and symbol"?

The idea is to put name+symbol in select (dropdown) list, and when user changes selection, text field beside dropdown list automatically changes and shows properly market_cap_usd value.

I was able to go forward and parse some data..

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $valuta => $vrednost) { 
        echo "<p>$valuta | $vrednost</p>";
    }
}
```

I have in mind that this is not the best way.. Do I need to create object (how?) so I could call "name" value directly or something else...

EDIT:

I find a solution for my problem with accessing values. I was also able to put those values to select/dropdownmenu element.

Here is my version:

```
        <form>
            <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">           
            <?php

            $url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';
            $content = file_get_contents($url);

            $json = json_decode($content, true);

            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option>" . $json[$key]['name'] ." (". $json[$key]['symbol'] .")</option>";
            }

            ?>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Maybe will someone find some useful thing here for their own "problems".

What is missing for me right now is the connection between selection in dropdown and displaying correct value beside, based on that selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP associate arrays, multidimension. How do I access them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687757/6521116)

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and how to [access array elements using square brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you'll need this code. I changed variable names to be more self-explaining.

```
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$decodedData = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ($decodedData as $currency) {
    echo "<option value='" . $currency["id"] . "'>" . $currency["name"] ." (". $currency["symbol"] .")</option>";
}
```

What `json_decode` does is that it converts a JSON string into a multidimensional array in PHP. Then, you can iterate over it using `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey use the code below.

```
<?PHP 
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

echo $json[0]["bitcoin"];
?>
```